# Datetime fetch incorrect data for second iteration

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query :

```
Declare @t table ( StartDate datetime , ENDDate datetime)

Insert into @t values ('2020-02-05 15:00:00.000','2020-02-05 15:30:00.000')
Insert into @t values ('2020-02-05 15:10:00.000','2020-02-05 15:20:00.000')

Declare @time datetime ='2020-02-05 15:11:00.000'

select top 1 * from @t
where StartDate <= @time 
order by StartDate desc
```

It gives me 2nd row as an output which is correct. Because time is 15:11:00.000.

Now If I pass

```
Declare @time datetime ='2020-02-05 15:31:00.000'
```

And I run the above query it still gives me the same output, But I want to show the 1st row as an output. What changes do I need to make to satisfy both the requirement with 1 query?

The reason I want to show the 1st row as an output: Because the enddate which is being passed is near to the end date of the 1st row, I can write the second query to fetch the data, But I need just 1 query wherin both the condition should be satisfied.

I tried this as well:

```
Declare @t table ( StartDate datetime , ENDDate datetime)

Insert into @t values ('2020-02-05 15:00:00.000','2020-02-05 15:30:00.000')
Insert into @t values ('2020-02-05 15:10:00.000','2020-02-05 15:20:00.000')

Declare @time datetime ='2020-02-05 15:11:00.000'

select *,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,ENDDate,@time) DTB from (
select top 1 * from @t
where StartDate <= @time  
order by StartDate desc 
) a
order by dtb
```

But I am still getting the same output.

Comment: my enddate is near to 15:31:00.000 so I should fetch 1st row

Comment: what is the `ENDDate` for ? It does not seems that you are using it in the query

Comment: I tried to use ENDDate with DateDiff but it was of no use.

Comment: with `15:31`, base on `Start` and `End` date, none of the rows satisfied. Why do you still want row 1 to return ?

Comment: Because If the time is 15:31 I still need to fetch 1 rows I cannot show blank record. So I want to check whose enddate is near to the given time and display it, but problem is I don't want to write seperate query for this

Comment: Please update your question and state the rules and condition that you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try this below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9898ea117e45c83901b3017ed915e7af)

```
Declare @t table ( StartDate datetime , ENDDate datetime)

Insert into @t values ('2020-02-05 15:00:00.000','2020-02-05 15:30:00.000')
Insert into @t values ('2020-02-05 15:10:00.000','2020-02-05 15:20:00.000')

--Declare @time datetime ='2020-02-05 15:11:00.000'
Declare @time datetime ='2020-02-05 15:31:00.000'

select TOP 1 *
from @t
where StartDate <= @time 
ORDER BY ABS(datediff(mi,ENDDate,@time))
```

Comment: Absolutely wonderful!!! This is what I wanted, And thanks to you I learned about ABS function..

Comment: You are most welcome @RedDevil. Nice to hear that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

** Your query only checking one condition `StartDate <= @time`, if you wanted to fetch the 1st record from your table which matches the condition then remove `desc` from your query.

```
select top 1 * from @t
where StartDate <= @time 
order by StartDate
```

** if you want to sort the date and fetch based on date difference between `StartDate` and passing date `@t` the use `DATEDIFF`

```
select *,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDate, @time) as dif from @t
where cast(StartDate as datetime) <= cast(@time as datetime) 
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDate, @time)

select top 1 * from @t
where cast(StartDate as datetime) <= cast(@time as datetime) 
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDate, @time)
```

Comment: There is no change in the output

Comment: yes, but what you are asking does not hold any logic so i tried to explain it how you would like it to behave.